# Why can't I save using Save Data or Save Model?

Tags: orange

I cannot seem to save any of my models, nor any of the data created from their training. What am I missing? The input is >15,000 images created in ~200 classes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Save Data (3)` widget does not save anything since widget does not get any data at the input - note dashed line connecting `Logistic Regression` and `Save Widget (3)`. Logistic regression does not output any data since it does not get any data at the input.

You neither can save the models this way since they are not trained on data. In your example, they just provide the learner to the `Test and Score` widget. In order to use the `Save Model` widget, the previous widget (e.g. `Logistic regression`) must get the data at the input which it uses for training. See the example in the [documentation](http://docs.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/widgets/model/savemodel.html).

Comment: Can confirm, I realised this a few days ago. Basically: make sure to connect all models to the "Image Embedding" etc.